# How to find min of a vector without Ord?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of `RTSPUrl` and I want to find the smallest item.

```
struct RTSPUrl { /* fields omitted */ }

fn main() {
    let rtsp_urls = std::vec::Vec::<RTSPUrl>::new();
    let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min();
}
```

However the compiler complains that `RTSPUrl` should implement `Ord`.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RTSPUrl: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:44
  |
5 |     let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min();
  |                                            ^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `RTSPUrl`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::Ord` for `&RTSPUrl`
```

But this type isn't from my crate as it's generated by protobuf. Is there any other thing I can do?

Comment: If it doesn't implement `Ord`, how do you know there is a minimum value? If I told you that the item at index 0 was the smallest one, how would you know whether I was right or wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`min_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by) and implement the ordering yourself:

```
let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min_by(|a, b| {
    // return an Ordering based on a and b
    Ordering::Equal
});
```

Or, if you're just ordering by some property of `RTSPUrl` that *does* implement `Ord`, you can use [`min_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by_key):

```
let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min_by_key(|url| {
    // return something that implements Ord based on url
    url.something()
});
```

You didn't specify what `RTSPUrl` looks like or how you would want it ordered by, but one of these options should work. [Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddc527cdb5e484b18e7d38641de44a87).

The same pattern (`*_by()` and `*_by_key()`) is used elsewhere like [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html?search=#method.max) or [`slice.sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Iterator::min_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by) and implement your own comparison, based on the contents of `RTSPUrl`:

```
let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min_by(|a, b| ...)
```

Your function should return an [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html), I believe.